# Creating a R function storing objects that can be recall but not displayed

Tags: r

Is it possible for me to create a R function that the output will not show every objects inside but you can call the object(s) inside it using `$` or `[]`, like the one below

```
abc <- function(a=1, b=2, c=3) {...}
#by default, abc() only the value of a will be shown but not b neither c

abc() 
[1] 1
abc()$a
[1] 1
abc()["b"]
[1] 2    
abc()$c
[1] 3
```

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot index functions. Period. End of sentence. Please read about R environments.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any good materials for me to start with?

Comment: @BondedDust - you kind of can, using the exact same syntax as OP - `abc <- function(a=1, b=2, c=3) {invisible(list(a=a,b=b,c=c))}; abc()$b`

Comment: OK, I capitulate. You can index the results of functions. So you proponents of this strategy should describe the necessary requirements for this function... say: All formals need to have default values and they need to return a list. I think it would need to be: `function(a=1, b=2, c=3) { cat(a); invisible(list(a=a,b=b,c=c))}; abc()$b` to meet the requirements of the OP.

Comment: Or you can return an object with a custom class and define a unique print method for that class that only prints the value of b from the list by default.

Comment: @BondedDust - I'm certainly no proponent of this strategy. I think it is probably largely pointless. But it's an interesting question, despite it's probably limited practical application.

Comment: @BondedDust I thought the same, but with `cat(a)`, the value of `a` will _always_ be printed, i.e. not only in the `abc()` and `abc()$a` cases.

Comment: @jbaums: Yes... that was what was requested.

Comment: @BondedDust Not quite, unless I've misunderstood. The OP's example doesn't print `a` when calling `abc()$c`. It only prints the value of `c`.

Comment: The OP asked that `abc()` result in a console displayed value of `[1] 1`. Admittedly the `cat` approach only displays `1` but if I used `print` I would get `[1] 1 \n
[1] 1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to return all values but only by default display certain ones, i think you best course of action would be to give the return object a custom class. One strategy is to just a list and give a custom print method for that list.

```
print.myvalues <- function(x) {
    print(x$a)
}
abc <- function(a=1, b=2, c=3) {
    ret <- list(a=a, b=b,c=c)
    class(ret)<-"myvalues"
    ret
}
(x<-abc(10,20,30))
# [1] 10
x
# [1] 10
x$b
# [1] 20
x[["c"]]
# [1] 30
```

But this might confuse the user when they go to use the number in any way because it's not really just a number

```
x+5
# Error in x + 5 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

A slightly more complex strategy would be to store the additional values as attributes and overload the `$` and `[` methods in such a fashion

```
`$.myvalues` <- function(x, n) {
    x[n]
}
`[.myvalues` <- function(x, n) {
    if(n=="a") return(`attributes<-`(x,NULL))
    attr(x, n)
}
print.myvalues <- function(x) {
    attributes(x)<-NULL
    print(x)
}
abc <- function(a=1, b=2, c=3) {
    ret <- a
    attr(ret, "b") <- b
    attr(ret, "c") <- c
    class(ret)<-"myvalues"
    ret
}
```

and use it like

```
(x<-abc(10,20,30))
# [1] 10
x
# [1] 10
x$b
# [1] 20
x["c"]
# [1] 30
x+5
# [1] 15
```

Here we preserve addition, of course nothing in particular happens to the `b` and `c` values. We could also overload the `+` operator if we wanted to carry the addition through the attributes. It all depends on how complex you want to make it.

Comment: The request was somewhat ambiguous, The specified behavior at the console would be satisfied by: `function(a=1, b=2, c=3) { cat(a); invisible(list(a=a,b=b,c=c))}`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it is what I want. But I am not fully understand how each steps work, is there any materials that can help me?

Comment: Also, how can I make `abc()$a` showing the value of `a` only and hiding `attr(,"b")` and `attr(,"c")` that will be shown by your method? Thanks.

Comment: @kitman0804 I've updated my example to fix the "$a" syntax. You can learn about this by reading about the S3 class methods in R.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one more question. Is there any restriction for the class name ("myvalues" in your example)?

Comment: Also, due to `attributes(x)<-NULL`, `a` always become a vector, is there any generalized way that `a` can be display as its original format, for example, if `a` is a matrix, the output of `abc()` is also a matrix. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @kitman0804 I don't know of any restrictions on class name other than it probably should follow the same naming conventions as a standard R variable name. Rather than removing all attributes, you remove only the ones you've set on the object. You'll just have to be explicit about what you want to remove. A "matrix" is really just an object that has a length-two "dim" attribute.

Comment: @MrFlick, Sorry, this is me again. I tried to remove `attributes(x)<-NULL` in `print.myvalues` in attempt to keep the original attribute of `a` (so that if `a` is a matrix, `abc()` will output matrix; if `a` is a list, `abc()` will output a list; ) but error occur "Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?"; What else can I do to deal with this problem?

Comment: Well, you need to at least remove the class attribute. You can use `unclass()` for that.

Comment: @MrFlick Do you mean replacing `attributes(x)<-NULL` by `unclass(x)`? 
I got errores for that.

Comment: Well, it would be better to describe exactly what errors those were. But you need to save the result of `unclass()`. So use `x<-unclass(x)`. or just `print(unclass(x))` for `print.myvalues`

Comment: @MrFlick when I use `print(unclass(x))`, i get `abc(a=matrix(1:9,nrow=3))
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`, if i use `x<-unclass(x)`, `abc(a=matrix(1:9,nrow=3))` `attr(,"b")
[1] 2
attr(,"c")
[1] 3` was not hidden

Comment: You haven't been clear on what you wanted. If you only wanted to remove some attributes, my comment from Jan 20 still applies. I think I've done all I can for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
> abc <- function(a=1, b=2, c=3) { cat(a); invisible(list(a=a,b=b,c=c))}
> abc()
1
> abc()$c
1[1] 3
> abc()$a
1[1] 1
> abc <- function(a=1, b=2, c=3) { print(a); invisible(list(a=a,b=b,c=c))}
> abc()$a
[1] 1
[1] 1
```